# do i need to set the value of the ONE side when adding an entity to a one-to-many collection?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

This seems like a super obvious question, but I haven't been able to find a clear answer.
I'm using FluentNHibernate automapping with the DefaultCascade.All() convention.

Entities are saving, but in one-to-many relationships I'm having to provide the one side on my many side even though i'm saving by adding to a collection.
An example will probably explain this better:

Lets say I've got these two classes:

```
public class Owner
{
    public virtual IList<PetDog> Dogs { get; set; }
}

public class PetDog
{
    public virtual Owner Owner { get; set; }
}
```

In order to add a new PetDog to the Dogs collection on an owner, I feel like I should be able to call

```
Owner.Dogs.Add(new PetDog());
```

and dispose my ISession.  However, I'm just getting the Owner saving and thats it.
If I explicitly set

```
Owner.Dogs.Add(new PetDog { Owner = Owner })
```

It works.

Is there a way to avoid explicitly providing that value?

Comment: Please can you update you question with the class mappings and the test code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by marking the Owner class as the owner of the relationship by setting inverse = false in the Owner mapping, i.e.

```
HasMany(x => x.Dogs)
    .Not.Inverse()
    .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
```

Then the owner_id foreign key in the PetDog table will be populated on commit, i.e.

```
using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    var order = new Owner() {Dogs = new List<PetDog>()};
    order.Dogs.Add(new PetDog() );
    order.Dogs.Add(new PetDog() );

    session.Save(order);
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

Alternatively, instead of using transaction you can call `session.Flush()` instead which will cause the new data to be inserted into the DB, i.e.

```
    var order = new Owner() {Dogs = new List<PetDog>()};
    order.Dogs.Add(new PetDog() );
    order.Dogs.Add(new PetDog() );

    session.Save(order);
    session.Flush(); // data persisted to DBMS here.
```

Please note that the use of `session.Flush()` is not recommended best practice. It is recommended that explicit transactions are used. Please see this [blog post](http://ayende.com/blog/3775/nh-prof-alerts-use-of-implicit-transactions-is-discouraged) by Ayende Rahien for further details.

Comment: just asking cause you included them and im still having trouble

Comment: No, you can also call `session.Flush()` or set the `session.FlushMode` to `FlushMode.Always`. I'll updated my answer with further details about the possible options.

Comment: Ignore my comment about setting the `FlushMode`to `Always`, looked into it further and its not a good idea.

Comment: using transactions made this work -- makes sense anyway.  i am just coming from an EntityFramework background so its a little bit diff than that.